# What bash code implements the equivalent of left(), right() an mid() from BASIC?

Tags: bash, substring

I am writing some code to test for membership of a group via `groups username` which returns a result like `vfclists : vfclists adm dialout cdrom plugdev lpadmin sambashare admin`.

The code for testing is like this

```
#!/bin/bash
UGROUP=$1
GROUP=$2
GROUPLIST=`groups $1`

echo $UGROUP
echo $GROUP
echo $GROUPLIST

if [[ "$GROUPLIST" == *"$GROUP"* ]]
then
  echo "$UGROUP is a member of $GROUP";
fi
```

The problem is the output of group includes the users name. How can I return the part of the output that appears to the right of the second appearance of the user name?

If the appearance of the username as the first group after the colon is not guaranteed is there some way to strip out the user name from the output altogether?

Comment: ...Hmmm, user is a real group vfclistss..

Comment: This is a job for sed. Or awk, but I don't swing that way.

Answer (score 1):

For `bash4`, you can adapt this for your needs (using associative arrays) :

```
declare -A arr

for i in $(groups); do arr[$i]=$i; done

user=root

if [[ ${arr[$user]} == $user ]]; then
    echo "$user exists"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just grep the output of `groups` for a match after the `:`?  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

SOME_USER="$1"
SOME_GROUP="$2"

if groups "$SOME_USER" | egrep ":.*\b$SOME_GROUP\b" > /dev/null
then
    echo $SOME_USER is a member of $SOME_GROUP
fi
```

The `\b` in the regular expression [matches a word boundary](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#The-Backslash-Character-and-Special-Expressions).

Comment: What does the b in the regex signify?

Comment: @vfclists: it matches a word boundary - I've updated my answer to link to the documentation for that.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever goes after the colon is a group name. It is possible to have a group with the same name as the user (as is the case for `vfclists`). To separate just the string after the colon, remove everything up to the colon:

```
groups=$(groups $UGROUP)
```

To remove a given word from the list a bit more problematic because you do not want to remove it if it is just a substring of a different word. This should work:

```
groups=$(groups $UGROUP)
groups=${groups#*:}
groups=${groups/ $UGROUP / } # Remove the word from the middle of the string
groups=${groups% $UGROUP}    # Remove the word if it is the last one
```

Answer (score 0):

Really good tutorial:
https://linuxhandbook.com/bash-strings/

Regarding title of this Question of:

**How to implement in Bash the equivalent of left(), right() an mid() from Basic**

See the above link at **Extracting substrings** title.